# Angular SEO dynamic sitemap (server.ts), not showing up on crawler

Tags: angular, seo, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I have a set of articles in my site, so I wanted dynamic sitemap.

I have converted the project to angular universal.
and I have made the following changes in server.ts file.

```
  server.get('/sitemap.xml', sitemap);

// site map
  async function sitemap(req, res) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function (e) {
      var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
      try {
        if (arraybuffer && arraybuffer.data) {
          var urlset = '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
          if (arraybuffer && arraybuffer.data && arraybuffer.data.articles && arraybuffer.data.articles.length > 0) {
            arraybuffer.data.articles.forEach(item => {
              if (item && item.id) {
                urlset = urlset + '<url><loc>' + environment.clientHostName + '/articles/' + item.id + '/' + item.seoSlug + '</loc><lastmod>' + item.updatedAt + '</lastmod><priority>0.8</priority></url>'
              }
            });
          }
          urlset = urlset + '</urlset>';
          let xmltext = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + urlset;
          res.type('application/xml');
          res.send(xmltext);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err, 'ERROR IN SITEMAP');
      }
    }
    oReq.open("GET", environment.api_url + 'common/sitemap', true);
    oReq.responseType = "json";
    oReq.send();
  }
```

when I deployed the code , checked in the browser it worked fine https://siteurl.com/sitemap.xml

it shows xml details

but in the crawler it shows like :
Issues
/
Duplicate pages without canonical
https://siteurl.com/siteurl.com.com/sitemap.xml

how can I fix it? or what am I doing wrong?